# How to pass parameters to a controllers in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to pass year and month to a controller. When the submit button is pressed, the year and month info should be passed to the action `show` of the controller `foo`.

I have edited my form as

```
<%= form_tag "/test" do %>
<%= month_field_tag :yearMonth %>
<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

How should I do to archive this in a view and how to get the passed parameter in `foo` controller?

Comment: Do you have a route created for that controller and that action? Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: `post 'test', :to => 'foo#show'`

Comment: @MarcusThornton more convinient will be to post your request to 'create' action `post 'test', :to => 'foo#create`

Comment: @MarcusThornton, could you please let me know what you are getting using my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 4+ You must have a params.require private def in your controller to permit the variables you define as "okay" to be parsed. Your controller will filter out anything not specifically allowed via the .require.

```
private
def name_of_controller_params
  params.require(:name_of_controller).permit(:yearMonth, :anothervar, :etc)                   
end
```

To see the params hash in your controller at the action point, you can insert this debug code into your relevant action. You can use this to see if your param is making it from the form into your controller's action.

```
    def show
      flash[:info] = "Params hash #{params}."
      other actions...
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
<%= form_tag '/test' do %>
  <%= month_field_tag 'month_value', '' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Then inspect params from `show` action to see if `month_value` is there.